# SOLVED: Error loading shared library libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 in VS Code extension integration test on CentOS 7 with Jenkins and XVFB

Tags: visual-studio-code, jenkins, centos, xvfb

I'm running integration tests for my VS Code extension on a CentOS 7 node using Jenkins and XVFB. During the test execution, I encountered the following error:

```
/home/mbesinga/workspaces/myvscode-extensions/.vscode-test/vscode-linux-x64-1.83.0/code: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exit code: 127
```

I've already installed the atk package using sudo yum install atk, and the library seems to be in the system as confirmed by sudo yum install atk. However, the error persists.

How can I resolve this shared library loading error in my Jenkins environment? Are there additional steps I need to take to ensure the test environment can locate the required libraries?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by adding two extra libraries: **libdrm** and **mesa-libgbm**.

Executed the following command:

```
sudo yum install atk java-atk-wrapper at-spi2-atk gtk3 libXt libdrm mesa-libgbm
```

Credit for the solution goes to this GitHub [comment](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1598#issuecomment-759149900)